# Install WPScan on macboock

Tags: ruby, macos, installation

I am running the installation of wpscan on my mackbook from the site:https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/10/install-wpscan-wordpress-vulnerability-scan.html

everything perfect until the command:`sudo gem install bundler && sudo bundle install --without test`

I get error:

```
[DEPRECATED] The `--without` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set without 'test'`, and stop using this flag
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler found conflicting requirements for the Ruby version:
  In Gemfile:
    Ruby

    wpscan was resolved to 3.7.11, which depends on
      Ruby (>= 2.4)

Ruby (>= 2.4), which is required by gem 'wpscan', is not available in the local
ruby installation
```

how to fix this?

Comment: A few things at play here. First, you probably don't have a Ruby manager installed like RVM or rbenv. I suggest you install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` then restart your shell then install Ruby with `rvm install 2.4`, then you can retry your `gem` commands. But note that when using RVM (or any other Ruby manager) you will **never** use `sudo`, so make sure you remove `sudo` from any of the commands in those instructions when doing something related to Ruby.

Comment: @anothermh I am not quite able to understand what you are telling me I have no skills in this, sorry for my ignorance. All I have is the guide I linked in the question, could you be patient and explain to me what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You should never run ruby gems with sudo. This is a really bad idea. Try running without using sudo.

```
gem install bundler && bundle install --without test
```